# Debugging with multiple library versions in intellij

Tags: debugging, maven, intellij-idea

We have a large maven project and not all of the projects specify the same version of various libraries, largely because these libraries haven't changed in some time. This causes problems with debugging because IntelliJ frequently selects the older version when it's the newer that's being used at runtime. Aside from fixing the poms, how can we get IntelliJ to resolve to the sources for the correct version of the library.

Comment: Have you asked to the support ?

Comment: @chepseskaf, support is monitoring tags and replies here =)

Comment: @CrazyCoder I "love" Jetbrains ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it except configuring your project dependencies correctly (to use the same library version in all the modules).

Comment: In a proper modular project setup (e.g. with OSGi), having all projects depend on the same (latest) version of a library is not "correct", it's bad practice. Dependencies should be based on API versions, not implementation versions. For debugging, the runtime deployed version is of interest, and this would be specified in a separate project. Unfortunately, creating a custom project in IntelliJ with the runtime dependencies doesn't help, as IntelliJ seems to randomly select from multiple versions of a library. No way to specify a "lookup order" as far as I can see...

Comment: External dependencies introduce different versions of indirect dependency libraries. How to resolve them?